# Informatica: reduced performance for simplet one to one mapping when target change from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have simple informatica(9.1) mapping(one to one) which loads data from flat file to RDBMS

it take 5 mins to load to Oracle db and 20 mins to load same file in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Can there be any source/pointers for performance improvement

Comment: all table structure , indexex , FK are same as in Oracle and hardware is different for both RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

A few things I can think of

- for both tests is the file local to the app server running the mapping?
- is the connection/distance between the app server and the data servers comparable
- Is "Target load type" of the Target in the Session Properties set to "Bulk"?

Comment: 1. for both oracle and mssql , source file is located in separate unix box

Comment: 3.load is using normal load

Comment: try changing it to bulk load for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the thread statistics in the session log to understand if the issue is while writing to db or while reading from file.
2. Is the PC server installed on Oracle db server? Is it the same case with SQL Server? Are SQL Server and PC server on the same box?
3. Is the mapping using ODBC or native connection to DB ?

Comment: 1. will check this  2. Inofrmatic , Oracle , MSSQL are instralled on diffeent m/cs   3. it is using ODBC connection